# How to set imageButtons

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I have my activity with several imageButtons http://postimg.org/image/4zuj7kmib/ (sorry for link but i have low lvl to post images here).

I want to make it look similar like this one http://postimg.org/image/5tdkph53j/

Here is one row of my tableLayout:

```
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/countTariffBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/countTariffBtn"
                android:text="Doporuč tarif"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/showTariffBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Tarify"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/showTariffBtn"
                android:text="Seznam tarifů"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/statisticsBtn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/plus"
            android:text="Statistiky"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_below="@+id/statisticsBtn"
                android:text="Statistiky"/>
        </RelativeLayout>

    </TableRow>
```

1) For removing borders of imageButton i can´t use style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"/> because i´m using API 9 so is there another option?

2) How can i get size of imageButton to know how big it is and to resize that image to this size? Is there a way how to get height and width from graphic design of layout?

3) How can i keep it with this margin to let these textViews be on the same spot like they are now?

Comment: I would start by removing the background drawable of the imagebuttons by using `@android:color/transparent`. That will allow just the images to be shown.

Comment: Ok thats another way to remove borders, but now buttons are big like the image is and i was satisfied with the previous size so is there that way how to get this size?

Answer (score 0):

set the background to be transparent, add padding, and set image source (src property) to be the drawable item you want. Don't forget to put image resources in different density directories (xhdpi, xxhdpi, hdpi, mdpi) to make them look good in all screens.